# yii2 TinyMce error in open modal converted in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, modal-dialog, tinymce

when opening modal the first time all correct but openning modal the second time the tynimce converted at textarea, if refresh the page the first  time all correct, alone whit this control have this problem

View

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'descripcion')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
                'options' => ['rows' => 6],
                'language' => 'es',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'plugins' => [
                        "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
                        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                    ],

enter code here

                    'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                ]
            ]);?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new proyecto();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

index

```
 <script>
      $(function(){
  $('.modalButton').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#modal').modal('show')
    .find('#modalContent')
    .load($(this).attr('value'));
    console.log(a);
   })
 });

    </script>
    <span title="Create"  value="'.$url.'"  class="modalButton" ><i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></span>

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens bcoz when modal is not initialized in the second time.
so for tinymice, on the close of modal destroy tinymice and then reinitialize tinymice with some delay time.
check following code

```
$('#popupID').on(
    'hidden.bs.modal',
    function() {
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true,
                'textareaID');
        setTimeout(function() {
            tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true,
                    'textareaID');
        }, 3000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // fix TinyMCE re-runs
    if(window.tinyMCE !== undefined && tinyMCE.editors.length){
        for(e in tinyMCE.editors){
            tinyMCE.editors[e].destroy();
        }
    }
```

Yours DOM-element already marked as modified by MCE. So... We must reset this 
My JS worked at my project